# Inverted Triangle of inputted text Python

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I am trying to take a string and print a descending triangle that removes one character until there are no characters left. For example if "hello" was inputted this would be the output:

```py
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

I am supposed to do it with both using with two separate functions, one using iteration and the other recursion so it outputs the triangle twice. This is what I have so far but I don't think it's very close.

```py
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(text[i:-1])
```

I also tried this but it just takes the entire string:

```py
for i in range(len(text), 0, -1):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(text, end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Neither of your code examples run due to indentation errors and an undefined variable.  You've shown no actual output; you haven't done anything to trace your program execution.  Don't simply throw coding changes at your computer; insert a useful `print` statement to learn how your code actually works.

Comment: Try to start by explaining in plain English words, exactly every step of the process you intend for the code to use. Then verify that you wrote code to implement that entire process, and then check that each thing in your code does the part of the process that you expect it to.

Comment: Also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: As posted, your question seems to be "I have this assignment -- oh, and more requirements, sort of.  I tried a couple of things, but they don't work, and I'm lost."  This is too unfocused for Stack Overflow.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Ask *one* question on code that you've traced, and we'll get you over the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in `reverse()` function to reverse the range

This way you don't need to print the whole string before it...

```
string  = "hello"

[print(string[:i+1]) for i in reversed(range(len(string)))]
```

```
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your indentation is wrong. I would solve your problem like this:

```py
text = str(input())
print(text)
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(text[0:-i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate(s)` you can access the indexes of the string. As i increases `-(i + 1)` decreases, from -1 to -len(s). `s[-(i + 1)]` accesses the string from the end to the beginning as i increases. You could also do this with `for i in range((len(s) - 1), -1, -1): print(s[:i])` where i starts at `len(s) - 1` and decreases by 1 all the way to 0. The `:` prints everything in the string up to `-(i + 1)` and `i` respectively

With the while loop you remove the last character of the string with each iteration until the string is empty.

```
s = "hello"

print(s)
for i, l in enumerate(s):
    print(s[:-(i + 1)])

print(s)
while len(s) > 0:
    s = s[:-1]
    print(s)

'''
hello
hell
hel
he
h
hello
hell
hel
he
h
'''
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Could you give a bit of explanation? It would help OP and future readers :)